# mysql insert error json decode

Tags: php, mysql, json

I am using the following code to convert json code to an array and insert the values into mysql. First I used a for loop to create the tables like this:

```
$url='http://www.coinchoose.com/api.php';
$contents = file_get_contents($url); 
$contents = utf8_encode($contents); 
$results = json_decode($contents, true); 

for ($i=0; $i<=22; $i++){

mysql_query("CREATE TABLE $symbol(
id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, PRIMARY KEY(id), timestamp BIGINT, symbol VARCHAR(3), name VARCHAR(20), algo VARCHAR(20), currentBlocks VARCHAR(20), difficulty DECIMAL (18,9), reward DECIMAL (18,9), price DECIMAL (18,9), exchange VARCHAR(20), ratio DECIMAL (8,4))")
or die(mysql_error()); 

}
```

Then I used another for loop to insert the values from the json api at http://www.coinchoose.com/api.php into the mysql tables, like this:

```
$url='http://www.coinchoose.com/api.php';
$contents = file_get_contents($url); 
$contents = utf8_encode($contents); 
$results = json_decode($contents, true); 
print_r($results);

$time=time();

for ($i=0; $i<=22; $i++){
$symbol=strtolower($results[$i]['symbol']);
$name=$results[$i]['name'];
$algo=$results[$i]['algo'];
$currentBlocks=$results[$i]['currentBlocks']; 
$difficulty=$results[$i]['difficulty'];
$reward=$results[$i]['reward']; 
$price=$results[$i]['price'];
$exchange=$results[$i]['exchange']; 
$ratio=$results[$i]['ratio'];

mysql_query("INSERT INTO $symbol VALUES (id, $time, '$symbol', '$name', '$algo', '$currentBlocks',  $difficulty, '$reward', $price, '$exchange', $ratio)") or die(mysql_error());  

}
```

I receive the following error, which I do not understand:

```
( ! ) Notice: Undefined offset: 21 in C:\wamp\www\api.php on line 45
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0004  706424  {main}( )   ..\api.php:0

( ! ) Notice: Undefined offset: 21 in C:\wamp\www\api.php on line 46
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0004  706424  {main}( )   ..\api.php:0

( ! ) Notice: Undefined offset: 21 in C:\wamp\www\api.php on line 47
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0004  706424  {main}( )   ..\api.php:0

( ! ) Notice: Undefined offset: 21 in C:\wamp\www\api.php on line 48
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0004  706424  {main}( )   ..\api.php:0

( ! ) Notice: Undefined offset: 21 in C:\wamp\www\api.php on line 49
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0004  706424  {main}( )   ..\api.php:0

( ! ) Notice: Undefined offset: 21 in C:\wamp\www\api.php on line 50
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0004  706424  {main}( )   ..\api.php:0

( ! ) Notice: Undefined offset: 21 in C:\wamp\www\api.php on line 51
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0004  706424  {main}( )   ..\api.php:0

( ! ) Notice: Undefined offset: 21 in C:\wamp\www\api.php on line 52
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0004  706424  {main}( )   ..\api.php:0

( ! ) Notice: Undefined offset: 21 in C:\wamp\www\api.php on line 53
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0004  706424  {main}( )   ..\api.php:0


You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'VALUES (id, 1369998276, '', '', '', '', , '', , '', )' at line 1
```

I hope that someone can clarify why I get this error. Any suggestions to better code the above, as I am sure it can be done in a prettier/better way are much appreciated. The code DOES work, because the values get parsed into mysql! However, the error still appears

Comment: $i<=22 ---> $i < count($results)

Answer (score 1):

You have wrong condition in your for loop.

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 22; $i++ ) {    // Notice the `<` and not `<=`
```

---

Or, as suggested in [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16856006/mysql-insert-error-json-decode/16856107#comment24309794_16856006):

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($result); $i++ ) {
```

Answer (score 0):

after `$results = json_decode($contents, true);` insert `$numcount = count($results);` and instead of `for ($i=0; $i<=22; $i++){` you should insert the variable like this: `for ($i=0; $i<$numcount; $i++){`